# Unable to import csv in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to import a csv into a dataframe but am unable to do that. Here is the code.

```
csv_2_df = spark.read.csv("home/jovyan/oneDay.csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
```

when I try to run the above piece of code I get the following error

```
 'Path does not exist: file:/home/jovyan/oneDay.csv;'
```

to set the context here I am trying to do that in a jupyter docker file where the root is set to /home/jovyan/ and I have uploaded my csv file. All I am trying to do here is to load the csv , I am able to do that using textfile API

```
data = sc.textFile('/home/jovyan/oneDay.csv')
```

but I am trying to use the CSV API as it gives me the option to drop malformed rows. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You first path is missing the leading `/`. You can also try `file:///home/jovyan/oneDay.csv` (in case the default is changed to something else).

Answer (score 0):

As @cronoik commented, try adding a forward slash to your path:

```
csv_2_df = spark.read.csv("/home/jovyan/oneDay.csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
```